# XNA/c# I cant get my projectiles to fire one at a time and finish their respective lifespan if i release the spacebar

Tags: c#-4.0, xna-4.0

thanks for reading.
Problem: Upon spacebar press i need my projectile to fire and continue its life regardless of another press or letting go of the spacebar.

below is both the code adding, updating, and drawing the projectiles.
I have tried numerous reworkings of this code but alas am not experienced enough to have found a suitable solution yet.

AddProjectile code below

```
enter code here


 //add projectile if spacebar is pressed

    private void AddProjectile(Vector2 position)
    {
        //i need somthing like this to make bullets autofire on phone
        //while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
        //{
        //    Projectile projectile = new Projectile();
        //    projectile.Initialize(GraphicsDevice.Viewport, projectileTexture, position);
        //    projectiles.Add(projectile);
        //}

       if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) ||
         currentGamePadState.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed)
       {
           Projectile projectile = new Projectile();
           projectile.Initialize(GraphicsDevice.Viewport, projectileTexture, position);
           projectiles.Add(projectile);
       }
    }
```

Update Projectile code below

```
private void UpdateProjectiles()
    {
        //update projectiles
        for (int i = projectiles.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {

            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) ||
                currentGamePadState.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {

               //adds particle to first projectile but not again until the next fire butotn press
                //particleEngine.EmitterLocation = new Vector2(projectiles[i].Position.X, projectiles[i].Position.Y);
                projectiles[i].Update();
                projectileOn = true;


            }
            //if projectiles not being fired remove them from the game screen 
            else
            {
                projectiles.RemoveAt(i);
            }



        }

    }
```

the Draw method that draws projectiles to screen

```
//draw the projectiles
                //***********************************************************
                 //using the if here allows control of projectiles to pass...
                 //...to the "currentstate of the spacebar (is pressed = fire)
                 /***/

                if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) ||
                    currentGamePadState.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.Count; i++)
                    {
                        projectiles[i].Draw(spriteBatch);

                    }
                }

                //remove projectiles and reset
                if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space) ||
                    currentGamePadState.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Released)
                {


                    UpdateProjectiles();
                }
```

So, this is what i have so far and as stated can get the projectile to worl fine , i just cant get them to continue their life (until a collision or they reach the end of screen) once i let go of the keyboard spacebar.
Any help woud be greatly appreciated
Thanks for reading once more.
. gruffy

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Just realised this was asked several months ago. OOPS. I will leave my answer though, if anyone will find it of any use.

Alright as far as I can tell your problem lies in your `UpdateProjectiles()` code. Specifically at:

```
//if projectiles not being fired remove them from the game screen 
        else
        {
            projectiles.RemoveAt(i);
        }
```

This means that when you are not pressing the spacebar you will be removing all the projectiles in the list. Also in your draw code you are calling `UpdateProjectiles()` specifically when the spacebar is released, which will clear your list of projectiles.

What you could do is, instead of letting the spacebar control if the projectiles are being shown, manage that seperately. What i mean is something like this:

```
//adds projectiles - only if the spacebar was pressed this update, 
//ensuring that only ONE projectile is added per press:

if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && previousKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space))
{
    projectiles.Add(new Projectile());
}

//updates the projectiles:

for(int i = 0; i < projectiles.Count; ++i)
{
    projectiles[i].Update();
}

//checks if projectiles have collided or are out of bounds:

foreach(projectile p in projectiles)
{
    if (PROJECTILE IS OUT OF BOUNDS || HAVE COLLIDED WITH STUFF)
    {
        DO WHAT NEEDS TO BE DONE;
        projectiles.Remove(p);
        break;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the only thing the spacebar does here is add new projectiles when pressed. Updating and removing of projectiles happens regarless of whether the spacebar is pressed.
Also in your drawing code i would recommend changing it to just:

```
//draws the projectiles regardless of whether the spacebar is pressed
foreach (projectile p in projectiles)
{
    p.Draw(spriteBatch);
}
```

This means that you will be drawing all projectiles in the list (or none if it is empty) no matter if spacebar is pressed or not. I would also reccomend moving `UpdateProjectiles()` to only be in your `Update()` call, as this frees up your drawing methods to just be about drawing stuff.

I am not claiming this is the most effective way to do this, but it will get the job done. One thing to note though, is that you will only be able to remove 1 projectile per `UpdateProjectiles()` call, but this shouldn't be a problem (it hasn't in my experience, at least) as you are updating many times  a second, and it will be rare that two projectiles needs to be removed in one update.

Hope this helps :)